# Get data from two tables and insert in one table through HQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have two entity classes `Student.java` and `Course.java` and they have `many to many` relationship between them I want to add one entry into their `@JoinTable` through hql like this :

```
insert into student_course(student_id,course_id) values('" + courseId + "','" + studentId + "')".
```

I want to use hql instead of sql. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a solution like this

```
 insert into student_course(student_id,course_id)
 select c.student_id,c.course_id from Student s join s.Course c
```

Comment: I use this as final Query query = getDatabaseSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "insert into student_course(student_id,course_id) select c.student_id,c.course_id from Student s join s.Course c );
        query.setParameter(0, student_id);
        query.setParameter(1, course_id);
        final int result = query.executeUpdate(); but I get exception .

Comment: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: student_course is not mapped [insert into student_course(student_id,course_id) select c.student_id,c.course_id from Student s join Course c ]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:

Comment: Any idae? Why I get this?

Comment: did you include student_course pojo and its mapping file.

Comment: how do I make pojo for mappin table ?

Comment: create entity classes student_course like entity classes Student.java

Comment: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: student_id

Comment: @pankaj Can you show the mapping for the entity classes?

Comment: what do you using for mapping , xml or annotation?